# Integration by parts for multivariable cumulative distribution function

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function, integral

How can I integrate by parts $$\int_A (y_1+\cdots+y_n) \,dF(y_1,...,y_n),$$
where $F$ is the cumulative distribution function for some random vector, $A$ is some Borel bounded set in ${\mathbb R}^n$.?

If it is possible, I need it to estimate $$\left|\int_A (y_1+\cdots+y_n) \,dF(y_1,...,y_n)-\int_A (y_1+\cdots+y_n) \,dG(y_1,...,y_n)\right|$$ in terms of $\sup_{y\in {\mathbb R}^n} |F(y)-G(y)|$.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
& \frac{\partial^n}{\partial y_1 \, \cdots \, \partial y_n} F(y_1,\ldots,y_n) \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac \partial {\partial y_1}\, \cdots\, \frac \partial {\partial y_n} F(y_1,\ldots,y_n) \\[10pt]
= {} & f(y_1,\ldots,y_n) \\[10pt]
= {} & \text{the density function}.
\end{align}
Riemann–Stieltjes integrals don't depend on absolute continuity, so there may be no density function, but the iterated nature of the operation of repeated differentiation above suggests working one variable at a time.
\begin{align}
& \int (y_1 + \cdots + y_n) \, dF(y_1,\ldots,y_n) \\[10pt]
= {} & \int y_1 \, dF(y_1,\ldots,y_n) + \cdots\cdots
\end{align}
So work on each term separately, integrating by parts in just one variable at each step. The integral shown in the last displayed line above is with respect to $n$ variables, but only one of the integrations would be by parts.

Comment: I do not understand which result I would get after integrating by parts in one variable only. I need it to estimate $$\left|\int_A (y_1+\cdots+y_n) \,dF(y_1,...,y_n)-\int_A (y_1+\cdots+y_n) \,dG(y_1,...,y_n)\right|$$ in terms of $\sup_{y\in {\mathbb R}^n} |F(y)-G(y)|$, where $A$ is some Borel bounded set in ${\mathbb R}^n$.